# Strange nodejs behavior

Tags: node.js

In my package.json I haved a records for one binary - flow-bin.

`"flow-bin": "^0.22.1"` 
into "devDependencies" and
 `"flow": "flow; test $? -eq 0 -o $? -eq 2"` 
into "scripts".

I uninstalled flow bin package and there is no "flow-bin" into devDependencies and removed value from scripts but

```
npm run-script flow --version
```

still working. How I can return to previous state - before installing?

I delete node_modules directory:

```
rm -r node_modules/
```

and do npm install again but it still working. What to do?

without nodejs the output is "normal" - what must to be:

flow --version
bash: /usr/bin/flow: No such file or directory

after new invocation of npm install there is nothing from flow into node_modules.

Comment: delete the relevant folder from inside node_modules

Comment: The question is edited - +1;

Comment: `npm install` will cause the folder to be created again... btw, what do you mean by "still working"?  `npm run-script flow --version` should print the version.. regardless of the module installed

Comment: The package is uninstalled and not exists at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at the code of [`npm-cli.js`](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/master/bin/npm-cli.js) we can see that the flag version simply displays version of `npm` and after `npm` exits:

```
  if (conf.version) {
    console.log(npm.version)
    return
  }
```

So try:

```
npm run-script NonExistentPackage --version
```

Comment: Thank you! I must check that some package is installed or not. Will use other approach.